# Is it posible to create some field with math function in SQL? if yes, how should i do it in this problem?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I'm working on a SQL table that save money transaction for every day. this is my table design:

```
    CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `balance_lastMonth` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `income` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `outcome` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `balance` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `member_id` (`member_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `transaction_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1
```

the balance field formula : `balance_lastMonth` + `income` - `outcome`
and balance_lastMonth is balance in the last month

is it possible to achieve it in one table? if yes how to do it? or may be there is better way to do it. i'm using 10.4.6-MariaDB.

Comment: What SQL are you using? [edit] your question to include the appropriate SQL version.  Yes, in some version of SQL you can use a calculated fields

Comment: i'm using 10.4.6-MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the balance using a query:

```
select t.*,
       sum(income - outcome) over (partition by member_id order by date) as balance,
       sum(income - outcome) over (partition by member_id order by date) - (income - outcome) as balance_lastmonth
from transaction t;
```

The simplest thing to do is to encapsulate this in a view and just use that.

If you actually want to store the results in the table, you'll need to use a trigger.  I don't recommend that approach unless you have some sort of requirement that the balances be stored.

Comment: thanks to your first answer it helps. but if the trigger method can make `balance_lastMonth` and `balance` automatically to be stored in the same table (or maybe in different table) in everytime income or outcome from the member is inserted or updated it would be great. i wonder what's the advantages or disadvantages if i use the trigger method in my case?